# MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification never called, movie loop

Tags: video, ios6, notifications, mpmovieplayercontroller, infinite-loop

Try to make a movie loop but MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is never call when video is finish.

Here is my code :

```
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dent4" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    self.moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayerController];

    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(playButton.frame.origin.x,
                                                    playButton.frame.origin.y,
                                                    playButton.frame.size.width,
                                                    playButton.frame.size.height)];

    self.moviePlayerController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    self.moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO];
    self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    self.moviePlayerController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayerController play];
```

Video play correctly once but don't fire end event.

```
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"END");
    if (note.object == self.moviePlayerController) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
            NSLog(@"REPLAY");
            [self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
            [self.moviePlayerController play];

        }
    }

}
```

Another things strange video is looping correctly on emulator (but moviePlaybackComplete never call) but on device is playing only once.

Anyone can help me ? I already see some post that said on fullscreen it's not called but i'm not on fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];
```

Comment: self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer me donne moviePlayer is unknow for MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer there is no such method moviePlayer inside moviePlayerController

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it to the moviePlayer not the moviePlayerController.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];
```

Comment: If its a MPMoviePlayerViewController than you have the property moviePlayer

Answer (score 0):

**TryOut this one**

**MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp;**

**1) Add Observer in viewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.mp.moviePlayer];
```

2) movieFinishedCallback Method

```
-(void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSNumber *reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason integerValue])
    {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:

            NSLog(@"Movieplayer is stopped");
            break;

        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:

            NSLog(@"An error was encountered during playback");
            break;

        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:

            NSLog(@"userExtied");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**3) To remove Observer in ViewWillDisappear**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.mp.moviePlayer];
```